# Combination involving two groups

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I'm trying to get the hang of permutations and combinations for a discrete math class.  One of my questions is as follows:

$$\text { You have a group of 30 people, and want to divide the group into two groups of 15 people each. }$$
$$\text { How many ways can this be done? } $$

My intuition is telling me to start with each group, say $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$.  Each group has the potential of selecting 30 people from the original group.  Therefore, I'd calculate it as

$$\frac{30!}{(30-15)!}+\frac{30!}{(30-15)!}$$

But this doesn't seem right.  If I'm done selecting all the possible people for $G_{1}$, then $G_{2}$ won't have $30!$ to choose from.

Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: If the groups are **labelled** it is $\binom{30}{15}$. If unlabelled, then $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \binom{30}{15}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first remark: it should be multiplication by the basic principle of counting, not addition, i.e, it should be $$\dfrac{30!}{15!}\times\dfrac{30!}{15!}$$

Now the way you count doesn't seem correct. In a group of people, we don't care about their order there, so you're counting each outcome in each group $15!$ more times. For example for the case of a group of $4$ people of $30$, if you pick $4$ people $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ this is just the same as $P_3,P_2,P_4,P_1$ or any other permutation. Thus your formula should be $$\binom{30}{15}\times\binom{30}{15}$$ But wait! Once you select 15 people to form group 1, there are only 15 people left to choose for group two. So in fact the correct answer is:$$\binom{30}{15}\binom{15}{15}=\binom{30}{15}$$

**Additional information:** Your exercise is a specefic case of distributing $n$ objects into $k$ groups such as the $i$th group contains $n_i$ objects (so we must have $n_1+n_2+...+n_k=n$ (in your case $n=30$, $k=2$ and $n_1=n_2=15$) and there's a general formula for counting the number of such combinaisions using [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_ways_to_select_according_to_a_distribution).

Comment: Thank you @Scientifica, that was a really helpful explanation!

Comment: @ptikobj Glad to hear so :D

Comment: Your answer assumes the groups are labeled.  If they are not labeled, you must multiply your result by $1/2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You're right, but they're indeed labeled since that's what the OP assumed: $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination. To be precise, $_{30} C_{15}$. You can see this by realizing that having one group, say {1,2,3...15} implies that you are excluding half of the population, namely {16,17...30}. This isn't really the proper notation for counting these things, but it is appropriate nonetheless. It doesn't matter what the second group is, because they are being excluded *because* the other 15 were chosen.

Comment: Your answer assumes the groups are labeled.  If they are not labeled, you must multiply your result by $1/2$.